# PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues readAgain parameter and new preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, default-value, android-preferences

I'm using `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context,R.xml.preferences,false)` to set the default values of the preferences in my application and I've noticed that if I add a new preference then my `PreferenceFragment` does not show a default value for it, even if it is set in the *preferences.xml*..

Is this due to the fact that I specify *readAgain* as false?

I know I can simply try-and-see, but I just wanted to be sure that the *readAgain* is meant for this purpose, i.e. re-read the default values not to re-set user settings but to set the new properties' default values. If this is exactly the purpose of the *readAgain* flag, then can you give me a reason not to always set *readAgain* to true, given that it does not reset user preferences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the `readagain` flag to true will ensure that all unset-default values are set again. That's the summary.

Setting the `readagain` will cause extra overhead since basically it means that, the code will go through the entire `SharedPreference`  once more to check them.  With the `readAgain` false,all it does is to check whether the file  ( **has_set_default_values.xml** ) which is used as a marker for setting default values is present or not.

In any case, It won't set any values that are already set .

Comment: I thought about the possible overhead... I have less than 10 preferences so it should not be an issue.. Is there any other way of monitoring if new preferences are added and force a preference reload only in that event? For example, can I understand when an application is launched for the first time after being updated? Maybe I could use a preference like *last_version_seen* and check it when application is started against the current version and trigger the preferences reload with *readAgain* set to true, right?

Comment: Refer the code of [ChangeLog](http://code.google.com/p/android-change-log/) . The name explains the use of that set of code. However , that aside, You can implement first-run check alone   by setting a `DefaultSharedPreference` for that.  ;-) .

Comment: @GianniCostanzi  Leave `readagain` to true.  If it's just 10 prefs , why bothering with lots more code. It's not lazy , it's just that it's not worth it to create another pref for that purpose of 10-20 prefs.

But if you liked the  `ChangeLog` library i have shown you , then add the bit of code in that file `cl.firstRun()` is in there somewhere . :-) .  Otherwise just leave it as true.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation of the parameter gave me the impression that it was going to overwrite _all_ the settings, but I tested it and confirmed that the behaviour you've described here is correct.